# Command for argmin or argmax?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

How can you get the argmin or argmax in Latex? Two solutions I found are:

```
\underset{x}{\operatorname{argmax}} 

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
```

Any other ideas?

[1] http://www.breakthru.altervista.org/?p=27

[2] http://researchonsearch.blogspot.com/2007/05/enter-argmax-argmin-in-latex.html

Comment: How do these solutions (especially the second) feel not right? The `\DeclareMathOperator` is *the* way to go in this case.

Comment: Personally, I like the look of `\text{arg}\,\max\limits_{\theta}\, `

Comment: what about how to make it work in Jupyter?

Answer (score 343, accepted):

As Pieter pointed out, the correct way to define argmin and argmax operators in LaTeX is:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
```

Actually, using the `amsopn` package would be sufficient but it's loaded by `amsmath` internally, which is recommended for math typesetting anyway.

The `*` in `\DeclareMathOperator*` places the underscored argument underneath the word rather than to the bottom right of it.

Comment: If you use `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}` you get rid of the ugly space between `arg` and `min`.

Comment: @rbp Why should one use `\arg\min` when simply `argmin` does the same?

Comment: @egreg you're right. I arrived at this one from some experimentation with other options, and didn't look back :)

Comment: In ConTeXt that is: `\definemathcommand [argmin] [limop] {\mfunction{arg\,min}}`

Comment: Explanation: I left the thin space (\,) between the arg and min because that's what the original poster had in the question, so I assumed that they wanted the space there.  Personally I would just do `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}`, without the space.

Comment: How can I make it work also in a context like `$\argmin_x{v(x)}$` i.e. when the code is between `$$` and not in equations?

Comment: what about how to make it work in Jupyter?

Comment: @CharlieParker This should work with MathJaX in Jupyter, and KaTeX already has `\argmax`.  What does not work for you in Jupyter?

Answer (score 173):

## Summary

In the sequel, LaTeX is assumed.

### Preliminary questions

#### 1. Should a thin space separate “arg” from “min”?

This is a matter of personal preference. The default definition for `\limsup` has a thin space, on the other hand “arcsin” is usually written without a space between the two components. Consistency is, as always, the keyword: using a macro definition will ensure it and also easiness in modifying the typesetting in the whole document, if switching from one option to another is needed.

#### 2. Should limits go below the operator in display style?

Also this is debatable and conventions used in the field the document is written for should be followed.

#### 3. Should the operator name be typeset upright?

Definitely, like all other operator/function names such as sine and cosine.

### Available tools

#### 1. `amsmath`

With `amsmath` one can do, in the preamble,

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min} % thin space, limits underneath in displays
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin} % no space, limits underneath in displays
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min} % thin space, limits on side in displays
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{argmin} % no space, limits on side in displays
```

Of course, only one of these should be used. In the document it's sufficient to type `\argmin` and the spacing around the operator will be the right one according to the common rules of math typesetting.

The seemingly different

```
\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}
```

is not really so, because it's essentially the same as `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}`; moreover it uses a deprecated command, that should be `\operatorname*`.

#### 2. No package

The following definitions are very similar to the ones above, in the same order

```
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,min}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,min}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}\nolimits}
```

#### With `\underset`

```
\underset{x}{\mathrm{argmin}}
```

This also was mentioned in the question and in one answer, but it is wrong, as the visual comparison will show.

#### 3. Differences

The “no package” version is much more rigid than the `amsmath` version, because this package can receive the `nonamelimits` option that will automatically change *all* operators such as `\lim`, `\max` that usually have limits underneath (in displays) to have them on the side. The same option would of course act also on newly defined operators, provided `\DeclareMathOperator*` has been used.

### Test document

In the following test document, the proposed definitions or constructions will be compared.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% limits underneath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminA}{arg\,min} % Jan Hlavacek
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminB}{argmin}   % Jan Hlavacek
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminC}{\arg\min}   % rbp

\newcommand{\argminD}{\arg\!\min} % AlfC

\newcommand{\argminE}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}}          % ASdeL
\newcommand{\argminF}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}\limits}   % ASdeL

% limits on side
\DeclareMathOperator{\argminG}{arg\,min} % Jan Hlavacek
\DeclareMathOperator{\argminH}{argmin}   % Jan Hlavacek
\newcommand{\argminI}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}\nolimits} % ASdeL

\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\cs{argminA}  & \argminA_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminB}  & \argminB_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminC}  & \argminC_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminD}  & \argminD_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminE}  & \argminE_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminF}  & \argminF_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{underset} & \underset{x}{\mathrm{argmin}} f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\}\\
&\cs{argminG}  & \argminG_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminH}  & \argminH_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \\
&\cs{argminI}  & \argminI_x f(x) &= \{x \mid f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Results

As predicted, many lines typeset the same. However, the macros defined with `\mathop` will not obey the `nonamelimits` option. Also the result of `\argminD` is clearly wrong, as the limit is typeset below “max” and not below the whole operator name.

The construction with `\underset` is wrong because it will not use the correct spacing after the operator: a thin space follows all others and it is the right way to typeset. Compare `\sin x` and `\mathrm{sin}x` to see this thin space in a different context.

Note that `\argminC` and `\argminA` give the same result, as well as `\argminD` and `\argminB`. Explanation: `\arg` and `\max` are already defined as operators, so TeX inserts a thin space if one directly follows another one. Using `\argminC` or `\argminD` just makes TeX spin its wheels a little more, with no advantage over `\argminA` or `\argminB`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Isn't `\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}` different in that it doesn't use `amsmath` package?

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo `\operatornamewithlimits` is an obsolete command defined by `amsopn` (a package loaded by `amsmath`, rarely used by itself).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason only `\underset` gave satisfactory results for with (with x being under argmin, not adjacent to it).

Comment: what about how to make it work in Jupyter?

Comment: @CharlieParker What's Jupyter? If it uses MathJax, then it's not LaTeX.

Comment: In Python code documentation I used the underset method including a `\;` to get the right spacing. It is the best approach for Sphinx mathjax extension.

Comment: @Attack68 MathJax is not TeX

Comment: Indeed, but this answer and my comment are helpful to Mathjax users who may stumble across it as I did when searching. There are limited, if any, answers to the same question in a Mathjax context.

Comment: @Attack68 I just tried with MathJax on Math.SE and `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}` provides the expected result. [Code (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM0U9.png) [Output (click}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFEAo.png)

Answer (score 40):

Use `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then:

```
\operatorname*{argmin}_\theta f(x)
```

[image]

Or similarly (for adding a space),

```
\operatorname*{arg\,max}_\theta f(x)
```

[image]

Comment: concise and to the point!

Comment: It works when used in `\begin{equation}` but not using `$$`

Answer (score 33):

I use `\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}}`.

Comment: +1 I like this - why overcomplicate things? This looks exactly the same as the `\DeclareMathOperator*` answer.

Comment: This yields "argmin". To get "arg min" (arguably the most usual notation), set it to `{arg\,min}`.

Comment: Google gave me 669,000 answers for "arg min" and 520,000 answers for "argmin", so I'd call it a tie. ;-)

Comment: this does work...? is there a missing import statement?

Comment: Google Scholar got me 171,000 for "arg min" and 116,000 for "argmin".

Answer (score 9):

Just another alternative (in some sense the poorer solution around, see comment below), could be to define `\argmin` in terms of `\min` and `\arg` commands.

```
\newcommand{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
```

In this way, 1) `\argmin` will behave <s>always</s> the same way as `\min`, 2) doesn't need `amsmath` or care about `\operator...` commands 3) **yes, the variable in not centered** (it is centered in the `min` part), but that may even be what you want (since it is centered in the same ways a `\min`, also the 'g' in `\arg` doesn't further lower the under-argument).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\begin{document}

\[ \argmin_x f(x) = \{x | f(x) = \min_{x'} f(x')\} \]
\[ \min_x f(x) = \{f(x) | f(x) < f(x_0) \forall x_0 \in R \]

\end{document}
```

[image: argmin]

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea. `\argmin_{x\in X\cap Y} f(x)` will break it completely.

Comment: What is the `\arg` command for anyway?

Comment: @ThomasAhle, `arg` is for the argument function (angle in the complex plane, $z = |z| e^{i \arg z}$. tohecz is right by the way.

Comment: @boycott.se-yo', good point.

Answer (score 6):

or you could use the underset command. For example:

```
    R = \underset{n} {\mathrm{argmax}} ~P(L_n|\mathbf{x})
```

Comment: Please don't use this. This makes `argmin` a `mathord` rather than a `mathop` and the spacing is incorrect. Moreover, this will not automatically adjust the limits in inline math mode.

Answer (score 6):

Using `\underset` does not require any other package. An above answer says:

> **With `\underset`**
>
> This also was mentioned in the question and in one answer, but it is wrong, as the visual comparison will show.

If the only thing "wrong" is that there is no space between the `argmax` and the `f(x)`, then just add `\,` (thin space) to fix the problem:

```
z = \underset{x}{\mathrm{argmax}}f(x)
```

[image]

```
z = \underset{x}{\mathrm{argmax}}\, f(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use `\mathop` and `\mathrm`, and eventually `\limits` or `\nolimits`, depending on the desired behavior when combined with `_` and `^`.  See below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{
nothing:
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}}
$\argmin_a^b$
$$\argmin_a^b$$
}

{
limits:
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}\limits}
$\argmin_a^b$
$$\argmin_a^b$$
}

{
nolimits:
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}\nolimits}
$\argmin_a^b$
$$\argmin_a^b$$
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

This works without any additional package. However it will create a new line.

```
$$\pi(s) = arg\max_\theta$$
```

Comment: `$$...$$` is not recommended to use with LaTeX. Better use `\[ ... \]` for correct vertical spacing.

Comment: This solution will not typeset argmax correctly. Here arg will be in italic (and with bad spacing), and max will be upright.