# How can I define a math operator behaving like \lim or \sum with limits?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to define `\ext` to behave exactly like `\lim`.

I tried `\newcommand{\ext}{{\mathrm{ext}}\,}` but that doesn't behave exactly like `\lim`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command for argmin or argmax?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `amsmath`, which is recommendable for math texts in any way, a similar definition to `\lim` is

```
\def\ext{\qopname\relax m{ext}}
```

since `amsmath`, specifically `amsopn.sty`, defines:

```
\def\lim{\qopname\relax m{lim}}
```

Comment: Why not use `\operatorname`? I think it is a robust command.

Comment: @Rushavski: I posted this solution because `\ext` shall behave exactly like `\lim`, not a bit different or even better. So I suggested the original definition of `\lim` in amsmath.

Comment: Curious: In what way would it behave different if I would use `\operatorname`?

Comment: Then you should have suggested `\DeclareMathOperator*\ext{ext}` which will behave exactly like `\lim` and has the advantage of not using internal `amsmath` macros. (The one difference is that there will be some local assignments that are totally irrelevant inside the `\mathop` for this particular example. Cf. `\DeclareMathOperator*\good{foo-bar}` `\def\bad{\qopname\relax m{foo-bar}}`.)

Comment: @TH: Maybe, I just focused on *exactly like*. So I showed how to do it in exactly the same way and where it can be found, straightforward. Hope that adds something (general practice in copying macro behavior), otherwise the link to the "duplicate" would have been sufficient. Give me downvotes for it. :-) I upvoted Gonzalos solution because it *is* good.

Answer (score 27):

Use `\DeclareMathOperator` or its starred form (if the operator should take limits):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

% \DeclareMathOperator{<command>}{<text>}
% if the operator shouldn't take limits
\DeclareMathOperator\ext{ext}
% if the operator should take limits
% \DeclareMathOperator*\ext{ext}
```

Comment: The stared version produces something that behaves exactly like `\lim`.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
\makeatletter
\def\ext{\mathop{\operator@font ext}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Does that do limits correctly?

Comment: sure, why should it not?

Comment: Sorry, the command name sort of implies that it only sets the font. It seems to work as intended though.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `\DeclareMathOperator`, there is also `\mathop` to be used with `\newcommand`. For example:

```
\newcommand{\ext}{\mathop{\mathrm{ext}}
```

Comment: `\mathop` is a tex primitive, so this definition is a hybrid, non-latexy.  if you look into the documentatin for `amsopn.sty` (`texdoc mathopn`) you will see that `\mathop` is used there for the "internal" definitions, but command naming quickly shifts into the latex realm.  you will also see that the choice of commands is stated to be governed by the amount of memory they use.  remember, `amsmath` and its kin were written when memory use still mattered.