# Different spacing caused by \newcommand and \def

Tags: macros

From the answer to my other question " [How can I define a math operator behaving like \lim or \sum with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/define-something-like-lim-but-for-another-name/13557#13557)", I tried:

```
\def\ext{\qopname\relax m{ext}}
```

and:

```
\newcommand{\ext}{\qopname\relax m{ext}}
```

In " [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)", it is said that they are basically the same and `\newcommand` is a bit more clever and does some extra checks. But it suggests that they should behave in just the same way.

But actually they do not. For the `\def` case, it seems to add extra spacing around `\ext` when I use it (just like `\lim` would). And `\newcommand` does not.

Why? What exactly is the different behavior for those more generally?

Comment: They should behave the same way. Note that `\def` is more like `\newcommand*`. For the same behavior of `\newcommand` you would need `\long\def`, but this does only matter if you define macros with arguments. Could you add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the space you mention.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  I just tried it, and I thought I could see the difference on one test but when I zoomed in then it disappeared.

Comment: I think in general normal users should stay way from `\def` as it overwrites existing macros without question. Usually one should only overwrite a macro if on know what it does and one is certain it will be OK to overwrite it. The classical example is of course `\span`

Comment: @Martin: Hm, I just tried. But I don't seem to be able to reproduce this. Maybe it was something different and lead me to this wrong conclusion.

Comment: @albert: that happens to the best of us

Comment: @Albert: I would prefer if either you delete the question or that it is closed. It isn't a real question (anymore) after all.

Comment: @Martin: I don't really want to delete it in the case that I stumble again upon it and when I am able to reproduce it. I would close it for now and reopen it later then. But I don't know how to do that. Maybe I lack enough reputation.

Comment: @Albert: I closed it for you. Just mark it for moderator attention if you want to have it reopened.

Comment: There's no real reason to use `\qopname`. I don't know what Stefan suggested that. You should be using `\DeclareMathOperator` in the preamble, or for one-off, you should be using `\operatorname`.

Comment: @TH: Stefan explained in a comment to his answer why he used `\qopname`. Still I agree with your recommendations.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes he did, but is isn't very compelling. `\lim` is defined that way for efficiency since they knew that `lim` didn't need any mathcode modifications. Granted `ext` doesn't either, but that's not really a good reason to use an undocumented macro rather than the standard interface.

Comment: @TH: It's not me you have to convince, I do already agree `:-)`