# How to make a \newcommand that acts like \dim?

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, math-operators

The `\dim` command is good at deciding how to space things following it: for example, both `$\dim M$` and `$\dim_A M$` look right (the subscript immediately follows the `dim`, whereas the non-subscripted version has a space before the `M`).

I'd like to make a similarly-acting command `\depth`. I've been using:

```
\newcommand{\depth}{\textnormal{depth }}
```

but this forces a space, so `$\depth_A M$` doesn't look good. I tried using `\xspace` as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/newcommand-and-spacing):

```
\newcommand{\depth}{\textnormal{depth}\xspace}
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything (there is no difference between using it and not, in the above command).

How can I get the right behavior?

Comment: See also [How can I define a math operator behaving like \lim](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/define-something-like-lim-but-for-another-name), [Command for argmin or argmax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax) and [How can I specify a long list of math operators](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-specify-a-long-list-of-math-operators).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\depth}{depth}
```

However, although `\depth` does not appear to be defined, it's used in some box contexts, so maybe it would be better to change the name:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Depth}{depth}
```

The space you see between "dim" and "M" is inserted because `\dim` qualifies as a math operator; and the space is inserted automatically also in `\dim_M X`, for instance, but not in `\dim_M(A+B)`. The same will be with `\Depth` that produces an operator named "depth".

The `\DeclareMathOperator*` variant builds an operator that takes limits above and below in displays (like `\min`).