# radical of polynomial A rad A

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Do we have something like `\rad` for the radical of a polynomial in LaTeX? I am writing in the equation mode within the `theorem` environment and everything is in italics. If I use `\text{rad}`, then I get rad in italics. If I use `\textrm{rad}` I get rad in Times New Roman font. I just want to display it in nonitalic format and in the same font as other parts of the theorem. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Use `\mathrm` or, better yet, `\DeclareMathOperator`, see [What is the difference of \mathop, \operatorname and \DeclareMathOperator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302) and [How can I define a math operator behaving like \lim?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13554)