# How do I center my subscript?

Tags: subscripts

How do I make the following subscript centred below the text?

```
$$\text{argmin}_{x,y,z,b}$$
```

As this one does automatically?

```
$$\Pr_{x,y,z,b}$$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I define a math operator behaving like `\lim`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13554/5764) The solution suggests using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: It says I can only use that in a preamble which I don't have/don't know how to make and the \newcommand option doesn't work for me.

Comment: The preamble is the part between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. You don't have that? You don't have access to that? Why not?

Comment: ...use `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}`, which would then allow you to use `\argmin_{x,y,z,b}`...