# LaTeXing cup product over an indexed set

Tags: symbols

```
\[\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i\]
```

I write this code and the summation variable i comes as subscript, to the right of the smile (cup product symbol in algebraic topology). I wish to have the index i underneath the cup product symbol, like it does with union, intersection or summation operation in place of the cup product.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very similar to [How can I define a math operator behaving like `\lim`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13554/5764) Use `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as

```
\[\underset{i\in I}{\smile}\alpha_i\]
```

The `\underset` command is provided by the `amsmath` package.