# latex: Undefined control sequnce

Tags: errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax)

For the following piece of LaTeX code,

```
{\hat \theta} 
    = { \argmin_{\theta \in \Theta}}
```

I got following error:

```
undefined control sequence={\argmin
```

How would I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

That error means that the command `\argmin` is not known to Latex.

This is probably because Latex does not know this command. Unless you explicitly define the `\argmin` command in your document, or you use a package that defines it, it does not exist. To fix this problem, either define it (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax)) or install a package that provides that command for you.