# How to put indices under argmin (using _ is not sufficient)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax)

How to put indices under "argmin" in: `\operatorname{argmin}_{z}`  ?

For the sum we can do something like: `\sum\limits_{z}`, but it does not work for the argmin example.

EDIT MWE:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{myequation}
  F = 
  \begin{cases}
    n + b + 1 & \text{if $a \neq \emptyset$}\\
    \tilde{z} = \operatornamewithlimits{argmin}_{\tilde{z}}\operatorname{dist}(z, \tilde{z}) & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: @egreg this does not work, I need z under argmin as a limit !
 
Also, I have the formula inside a \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} bloc, and it seems that I can not put \[ \operatornamewithlimits{argmin}_z \] inside this bloc !

Comment: Please, look at the linked question. Defining `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}` and using `\argmin` in the body of the document is the best strategy. In your case the limits are *not* put under "argmin" because `cases` typesets its lines in textstyle. Load `mathtools` and use its `dcases` environment.

Comment: @user995434 -- you need to insert `\displaystyle` before the `\operatornamewithlimits'.  the `cases` environment is based on `matrix`, which assumes `\textstyle` by default.  this isn't very well documented, so i'll add a note to improve the situation the next time the documentation is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}\limits_{\tilde{z}}` to put a z tilda underneath the argmin.  Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}_z= \ldots
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{myequation}
  F = 
  \begin{cases}
    n + b + 1 & \text{if $a \neq \emptyset$}\\

    \tilde{z} = \operatornamewithlimits{argmin}\limits_{\tilde{z}}\operatorname{dist}(z, \tilde{z}) & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The long command name has been obsolete for some years; indeed it's in `amsopn` just for back compatibility: `\def\operatornamewithlimits{\operatorname*}`

Comment: I know that! The macro name `\operatornamewithlimits` is selfexplanatory, but `\operatorname*` not ...

Comment: Maybe, but it's undocumented.

Comment: @egreg -- niggle: if you check `texdoc amsopn`, `\operatornamewithlimits` *is* documented (and said to be retained "for the time being" for backwards compatibility), but `operatorname*` is not, except in the cited definition.  (of course, the number of people who actually read the `amsopn`-specific documentation probably approaches zero.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The *-variant is in `amsldoc.pdf`, of course. Not that many people read this one, either. :(

Comment: I have a formula inside a `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` bloc, and it seems that I can not put `\[ \operatornamewithlimits{argmin}_z \]` inside this bloc !

Comment: @user995434: see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert your edited example works alone, but in my formula (see my edited question) it doesnt work, it have the same effect as: \operatorname

Comment: @user995434: See my answer. You also need `\limits` when in math text style