# \DeclareMathOperator vs. \operatorname*

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

To define my own math operators, I usually use [amsmath](http://'s)'s `\DeclareMathOperator`. However, with `\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}` does not give me the desired "limits" under the operator even in displayed math.

Searching this site, I found `\operatorname*` (and [`\operatornamewithlimits`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62625/how-to-put-indices-under-argmin-using-is-not-sufficient)) which implements the desired behavior.

```
\begin{equation}
    \operatorname*{Res}_{x = y} \frac{1}{x - y}
    = 1.
\end{equation}
```

gives

[image]

However, I'm still unsure if this can or should somehow be combined with `\DeclareMathOperator` and generally when to choose `\operatorname*` over `\DeclareMathOperator` (besides this particular case).

Comment: You have `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

Comment: @Bernard Ah, I might have guessed... :)

Comment: Or have read the amsmath documentation… ;o)