# \underset italicizes whatever in it

Tags: align, math-operators, italic

I'm trying to write a simple argmin equation. However `\underset` command italicizes whatever in it. Here is my code:

```
\begin{align}

\label{Eq:argmin}

&{x}={\arg\underset{p}{\rm min}}\{N_{clip}(\bar{\pmb{\rm x}})\}\\

&{\rm subject~to}~ {p}~ \epsilon~\Theta \nonumber

\end{align}
```

and here is the output

[image]

It is strange because I used the same code many times before and it was working properly. Only in this file I have that problem... Do you have a guess about the source of that error or any solution to get rid of it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should use `\min` instead of `{\rm min}`...

Comment: I think it is not the main problem, but thank you in anyways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some guidelines...

- Don't wrap your math components in braces; `{x}` removes the appropriate spacing around `x`.
- Don't use `{\rm ..}` for roman text font. Rather use `\text{..}` as supplied by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).
- `\in` denotes "member of", as opposed to `\epsilon`.
- If you're using proper *operators*, you can underset an argument using "limits".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{Eq:argmin}
  & x = \argmin_p \{N_{\text{clip}}(\bar{\mathbf{x}})\} \\
  & \text{subject to } p \in \Theta \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

For better/different definitions of `\argmin`, see [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7jhG.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7jhG.pngSome guidelines...

- Don't wrap your math components in braces; `{x}` removes the appropriate spacing around `x`.
- Don't use `{\rm ..}` for roman text font. Rather use `\text{..}` as supplied by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).
- `\in` denotes "member of", as opposed to `\epsilon`.
- If you're using proper *operators*, you can underset an argument using "limits".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{Eq:argmin}
  & x = \argmin_p \{N_{\text{clip}}(\bar{\mathbf{x}})\} \\
  & \text{subject to } p \in \Theta \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

For better/different definitions of `\argmin`, see [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764)

Comment: It definitely works, thank you very much :)