# Latex: How do I write "\sim_G" but so that the G is directly underneath the "\sim"?

Tags: formatting, subscripts

In Latex, How do I write "\sim_G" but so that the G is directly underneath the "\sim"?

Comment: See [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/5764) or [Command for `argmin` or `argmax`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764) You have to define it as a math operator.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to use it often, you can declare it to be a math operator. If used rarely, you can make a stack or an `\underset`.  Here, I show all ways. Notice I made the stack a `\mathrel`, rather than `\mathop`, which has a slightly larger horizontal spacing.  Choose what suits.  When using the `\stackunder`, the vertical gap may be set with the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\simop}{\sim}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[A \underset{G}{\sim} B \mathrel{\stackunder[1.8pt]{\sim}{\scriptstyle G}} B \simop_G A \]
\end{document}
```

[image]