# Equation with \argmin inside table

Tags: tables, equations

I want the equation to properly show the argmin tag with variable at the bottom inside a table. In my case it is showing as a subscript. I tried everything but cant get this done. 
The following is a part of my code compiling fine but not as desired

```
\multicolumn{4}{l}{ $\begin{array} {lcl} \mathbf{r}^i \longleftarrow \argmin_\mathbf{r}\;\Vert \mathbf{r}  \Vert_1 \;\;\;\;\mbox{subject to}\;\;\;\;   \mathbf{y}= \mathbf{A}\mathbf{r} \end{array} $ }
\begin{tabular}{ll|l|l|l|} \hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Algorithm:}                                                    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}Inputs: CS measurement vector for a speech frame $\mathbf{y}$ \\ Outputs: predictor $\mathbf{a}^i$, residual $\mathbf{r}^i$ \\ $i$ = 0, \\ Initialize dictionary: $h^i=rand, \mathbf{H}^i= conv(h)$             \\\end{tabular}} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{while} halting criterion false \textbf{do}}        \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{1.}           &                          \\
                              & \multicolumn{4}{l}{$\begin{array} {lcl} 
                              \mathbf{x}^i =\mathbf{H}^i\mathbf{r}^i \end{array}$}                           \\
2.                            & \multicolumn{4}{l}{
$\begin{array} {lcl} \mathbf{a}^i \longleftarrow \argmin_\mathbf{a} \; \Vert \mathbf{r}\Vert_2 + \gamma\Vert\mathbf{a}\Vert_1 \;\;\; \mbox{subject to}\;\; \mathbf{x}^i=\mathbf{X}^i\mathbf{a+r} \end{array}$\vspace{1em}}                        \\
\multirow{4}{*}{3.}           & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\; \mbox{Estimate the vocal tract impulse response}}                         \\
                              & \multicolumn{4}{l}{
                             $\begin{array} {lcl} 
                              h^{i+1} \;\; \mbox{given the predictior estimate}\;\;\mathbf{a}^i \end{array}$}                           \\
                              & \multicolumn{4}{l}{$\begin{array} {lcl}
                              \mathbf{H}^{i+1}= [conv(h^{i+1})] \end{array}$ 
                                            }            \\
                              & \multicolumn{4}{l}{$\begin{array} {lcl}
                              i=i+1; \end{array}$         }                              \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{end while}} \\ \hline                                        
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Desired Output
need argmin with variable at bottom not as subscript like this
 [image]

Comment: It is very hard to see either the intention or the problem with a code fragment. Please edit the question to be a _complete_ document starting `\documentclass` and describe the required output from the document.

Comment: It mostly depends on how you define `\argmin`. Without this information it's impossible to give advice. But, please, make an example that can be compiled.

Comment: If you defined `\argmin` as an operator - [Command for argmin or argmax?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764), then you may have to issue `\displaystyle` inside your `array` in order for it to be properly set underneath it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reasonable way to define `\argmin` is via the `\DeclareMathOperator` command of `amsopn` loaded most conveniently via `mathtools`.  To get limits to behave like those on `\lim` you should use the starred version of the declaration:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
```

Then in displayed mathematics limits will be placed under the text "argmin".  If you are in inline mathematics you can use `\limits` or `\displaystyle` to get this effect:

[image: Sample argmins]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\begin{document}

\( \argmin_r \) vs.\ \( \argmin\limits_r \),
\begin{equation*}
  \argmin_r
\end{equation*}
and \( \displaystyle\argmin_r \).

\end{document}
```

For your sample code, you seem to be trying to display an algorithm.  I would strongly suggest you use the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages for this rather than multiple `tabular`s.  Without knowing exactly what your algorithm is something like the following seems to be close to the desired output:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,mathtools}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator{\conv}{conv}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Example algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE CS measurement vector for a speech frame \( \mathbf{y} \)
    \ENSURE predictor \( \mathbf{a}^i \), residual \( \mathbf{r}^i \)
    \STATE \( i=0 \)
    \STATE Initialize dictionary: \( h^i=\text{rand} \), \(
    \mathbf{H}^i= \conv(h) \)
    \STATE \( \mathbf{r}^i \longleftarrow \argmin\limits_{\mathbf{r}}
    \norm{\mathbf{r}}_1 \) subject to \( \mathbf{y}=
    \mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}   \)
    \WHILE{halting criterion false}
    \STATE \( \mathbf{x}^i =\mathbf{H}^i\mathbf{r}^i \)
    \STATE \( \mathbf{a}^i \longleftarrow \argmin\limits_{\mathbf{a}}
    \norm{\mathbf{r}}_2 + \gamma\norm{\mathbf{a}}_1  \) subject to \(
    \mathbf{x}^i=\mathbf{X}^i\mathbf{a+r} \)
    \STATE Estimate the vocal tract impulse response
    \STATE \( h^{i+1} \) given the predictior estimate \( \mathbf{a}^i \)
    \STATE \( \mathbf{H}^{i+1}= [conv(h^{i+1})] \)
    \STATE \( i=i+1 \)
    \ENDWHILE
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```