# There is no line here to end \end{frame} with beamer

Tags: beamer, line-breaking

I try to compile these code but I get this error :

> There is no line here to end \end{frame}

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Traduction automatique statistique}
     \begin{itemize}
      \item Fondée sur la théorie d'estimation probabiliste [Brown e\textit{t al.}].
      \item Repose sur l'hypothèse que toute phrase d'une langue est une traduction possible d'une phrase dans une autre langue.
     \end{itemize}
       \begin{block}{Equation fondamentale}
       \\Soit $f$ une phrase source : 
      \\Le système de traduction automatique statistique : recherche de la phrase en langue cible $e$ ayant la plus grande probabilité d'être la traduction d'une phrase source $f$.
    \begin{equation}
    \hat{e} = \arg\max_{e} {P(e | f)}
    \end{equation}
      \end{block}
    \end{frame}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> \begin{block}{Equation fondamentale}
>          \\Soit $f$ un/e phrase source :

the first line in an paragraph cann not start with `\\`

Answer (score 2):

Forcing line breaks via `\\` is not always ideal. Rather set the content with a blank line to indicate a paragraph break (or an explicit `\par`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5255/5764
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{P(#1)}
\newcommand{\given}{\mid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Traduction automatique statistique}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Fondée sur la théorie d'estimation probabiliste [Brown e\textit{t al.}].
    \item Repose sur l'hypothèse que toute phrase d'une langue est une traduction possible d'une phrase dans une autre langue.
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{block}{Equation fondamentale}
    Soit~$f$ une phrase source :

    Le système de traduction automatique statistique : recherche de la phrase en langue cible~$e$ ayant 
      la plus grande probabilité d'être la traduction d'une phrase source~$f$.
    \begin{equation}
      \hat{e} = \argmax_e \prob{e \given f}
    \end{equation}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```