# Correct typesetting of one line formulas with underscored-argument operators and double subscripts/superscripts

Tags: math-operators, subscripts, superscripts, size

I'm having some trouble regarding the layout of nested subscripts/superscripts when used as underscored argument of argmin/min/max operators.

I have defined \argmin{} operator as:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
```

and then used inside:

```
\[\bm \theta_c^p \coloneqq  \adjustlimits\argmin_{\bm \theta_c \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{p} } }  \max_{\bm \theta \in \mathcal{D}_{\bm \theta}} \left\| \bm \theta - \bm \theta_c \right\|_p \]
```

in order to get:

[image]

My issue is that the actual output is not completely satisfactory mainly owing to wrong size of the subscript 'p' of 'n': they are both scriptscriptstyle so they have the same size and it results in a quite odd layout. I have already tried manipulating the size with no success whatsoever, even with \scalebox.

Which could be a simple and clean solution to this problem?

EDIT: I removed the part of the question that makes it a duplicate, the rest of the question is completely different from the "height issue" of adjacent operators (thanks to the use of \adjustlimits it is not an issue anymore)

Comment: For the last problem, use `_{\min}` instead of `_{min}`. You also have a  problem with the layout of `\argmin` (thin space between `arg` and `min`).

Comment: A simple solution would be `\smash{...}`, which makes the argument have no height. You could use this to eliminate the depth of the `g` and the height of the `^{n_p}`. However, the formulas will be too close then. So instead you could do the opposite and add a `\vphantom` to the other part.

Comment: Regarding the mark as duplicate, I fixed the question so that now it is a totally different subject.
@egreg that works perfectly, it fixes the height issue, but not the size issue in the subscript of the superscript.

Comment: @Bernard also this simple solution is perfect. As regards the thin space, I have followed the advices in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax

Comment: @Scz it looks like I'm placing that command in the wrong way since it does not influence the layout

Comment: @Vexx23 I voted for reopening, but there's not really much you can do: at 10pt size, second level super/subscripts are at 5pt size, making them smaller will imply unreadability.

Comment: You can use a set notation instead of subscripts.

Comment: The notation `\mathbb{R}^{n_{p}}` to denote the vector space `\mathbb{R}^{n}` under the p-norm is very awkward. And, by the way, useless, because the vector space is independent of the norm you consider over it.

Comment: @egreg I understand, and using 11pt or 12pt is there any chance to have different sizes for the two levels (I think they are 2nd and 3rd level)? 
\mathbb{R}^{n_{p}} indicates only the cartesian space of dimension n_p (number of parameters), the 'p' of n_p is not linked to the L^p-norm.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Do you mean replacing \mathbb{R}^{n_p} with a simple letter?

Comment: @Vexx23 Well, using the same symbol for two different purposes in the same formula is not really the best thing to do.

Comment: No - I have written out what I mean in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a smaller subscript with a trick:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{4}{4}


\begin{document}

\[
\bm{\theta}_c^p \coloneqq
\adjustlimits\argmin_{\bm{\theta}_c \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{p}}}
             \max_{\bm{\theta} \in \mathcal{D}_{\bm \theta}}
             \lVert\bm{\theta} - \bm \theta_c \rVert_p
\]
\[
\bm{\theta}_c^p \coloneqq
\adjustlimits\argmin_{\bm{\theta}_c \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{$n_{p}$}}}
             \max_{\bm{\theta} \in \mathcal{D}_{\bm \theta}}
             \lVert\bm{\theta} - \bm \theta_c \rVert_p
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, using a symbol with two different meanings in the same formula is not really recommended.

Comment: I think n_p is used because all the other letters, usually employed for integers, are used for different purposes (number of input p, number of outputs q, delay on the input m, delay on the output n, etc.) but yet you have made a very good point, this notation should be modified. Anyway the problem could arise also with consistent notations, so this solution will be useful anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on my comment, you should remember that you do not absolutely have to put the specification of the domain of `\max` or `\min` or ... as subscript to the word, but can use set notation instead, e.g.

```
\max \{ (x-3) : x \in [-1,1] \}
```

instead of `\max_{x\in [-1,1]} (x-3).  This particularly appropriate when the domain specification is long and/or involves many levels of sub/superscripts.  In you case, you could apply the technique to the outer argmin:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,bm}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\newcommand{\btheta}{\bm \theta}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \btheta_c^p \coloneqq
  \argmin
  \Bigl\{
    \max_{\btheta \in \mathcal{D}_{\btheta}} \norm{\btheta - \btheta_c}_p
    : \btheta_c \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{p} }
  \Bigr\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know this kind of notation yet, it is most useful, especially when writing very long constraints in the argument for linear programming or polynomial optimization problems