# how do i center the limits for multiple sum

Tags: amsmath

how do i center the limits for multiple sum like what we usually  do for integral ,,, in other way, is there command like `\idotsint` for sum?

for example:

`\sum\cdots\sum\limits_{n_1^2+n_2^2+...+n_N^2<\lambda}`

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable.

Comment: sorry but  it is one question, so, is there answer for it plz

Comment: one question with two different problems ... but more important is: provide complete small document beginning with`\documentclass{...}`and with `\end{document}` on the end.

Comment: Related: [Command for `argmin` or `argmax`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764)

Comment: Related: [What is the difference of `\mathop`, `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84302/5764)

Answer (score 1):

There is now....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sdotsum}{\sum\cdots\sum}

\begin{document}
    \[
\sdotsum\limits_{n_1^2+n_2^2+...+n_N^2<\lambda}
    \]
\end{document}
```