# environment of cases mess up the math operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, cases

Thanks to [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax) question, I have defined `argmin` operator. It works fine when I use it in equations except for when I apply it in `cases` environment. As you see, the `x` becomes an index instead of being underneath of `argmin`.

[image: argmin cases latex]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x^*=\argmin_x x^2-3x+1
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x^*=\argmin_x x^2-3x+1 \\
x>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather use `equation` than `align` for a single-equation math display. It makes syntactically sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, since each entry within a `cases` environment is set using `\textstyle`, making sub-/superscripts to an operator be set beside rather below/above it. You either need to force `\displaystyle`, or use the `dcases` environment from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  x^* = \argmin_x x^2 - 3x + 1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{dcases}
    x^* = \argmin_x x^2 - 3x + 1 \\
    x > 0
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```