# Can anybody help to write the mathematical equation with latex

Tags: equations, mathematics

[image]

also, can anyone suggest me good pdf file for it to learn the coding maths in latex

Thank you

Comment: Welcome. What did you try? Did you read about `$ ... $` math mode?

Comment: not yet. i am trying to write a equation which i have posted as photo in my question

Comment: Related: [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764)

Comment: For instructions on dealing with math somewhat above the bare-bones basic $...$ (in-line) and equation (display) input, see the [amsmath users guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) and [example paper](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/testmath.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inline math, use `$` delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$a_{\max} =  \max\limits_{0\le a\le\mathrm{argmin}(a(t))} a(t)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For display math, use `\[...\]` delimiters for unnumbered equations, or one of the various environments, such as `equation` for numbered equations.  Or, with the `amsmath` package, something from the `align` family of environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
OP comments: 
could you please help to write codes for these four equations? 
thank you very much in advance. 
\begin{align}
T_d=T_\mathrm{upper}-T_\mathrm{Lower}\\
%
T_\mathrm{upper} = \min\{t||a(t)|\ge a_\mathrm{threshold}\}\\
%
T_\mathrm{lower} = \max\{t||a(t)|\ge a_\mathrm{threshold} \}\\
%
a_\mathrm{threshold} = 10\% \max(|a(t)|)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please help to write codes for these four equations. thank you very much in advance. 1. T_d=T_upper-T_Lower   2. T_Upper=min⁡{t||a(t)|≥a_Threshold}
3. T_Lower=max⁡{t│|a(t)|≥a_Threshold }
4. a_Threshold=10% max⁡(|a(t)|)

Comment: @maths See my edit.  You really need to get a reference tutorial for basic LaTeX math.

Comment: Thank you steven. Yes i am looking basic tutorial currently.