# Label position in equation environment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, numbering

I am looking for a way to align the label of an equation environment to the 
base line of the formula text. The default behavior of

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{llr} 
\hat x &= \underset{x} {\text{arg\,min}} & f(x)+ \sum_i \lambda_i g_i(x)
\end{array} \tag{SomeLabel}
\end{equation}
```

seems to produce

[image: equation]

Here, the label is actually vertically centered to the whole equation. I think it would be nicer if it was aligned with the base line. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately "you're doing it wrong." There's no need for an `array` here.

Comment: Also see [Command for argmin or argmax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764)

Comment: If you *must* use `array`, move the label down one line, just before the `\end{equation}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why `array`?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat x = \argmin_{x} f(x)+ \sum_i \lambda_i g_i(x)
\tag{SomeLabel}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are absolutely right. I used 'array' because sometimes there are additional constraints to the optimization problem, so multiple lines. But, here it is not needed. Thanks.