# can somebody help me write my equation like the image given below

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
\begin{equation}
 f (u_p) = f(x)={(f(u_i ),                 d(u_p,u_i)=0 
 argmax_{v \in V} \sum{i=1}^{k} wD(v,f(u_i )) ,& otherwise )}  (5)
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `cases` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
      f(u_p) = f(x)= 
      \begin{cases}
        f(u_i),& d(u_p,u_i)=0 \\
        \arg\max_{v \in V} \sum_{i=1}^{k} wD(v,f(u_i )), & \textit{otherwise} 
      \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want to replicate the mistakes, such as the italic “max” and ”otherwise”.

Here are two possibilities, the latter replicates the alignment in the picture using `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f (u_p) = f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  f(u_i), & d(u_p,u_i)=0 \\
  \argmax_{v \in V} \sum_{i=1}^{k} wD(v,f(u_i)), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Alternative, like in the picture
\begin{equation}
f (u_p) = f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  f(u_i), \hfill d(u_p,u_i)=0 \\[1ex]
  \argmax_{v \in V} \sum_{i=1}^{k} wD(v,f(u_i)), \quad\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndrewRay Oh, right.

Comment: What is better in defining `\argmax` instead using `\arg\max`?

Comment: @arne Try, in display math mode, `\argmax_{x\le 2}` and `\arg\max_{x\le2}`. Besides, `\arg` has a completely different meaning.

Comment: I found a nice explanation at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/command-for-argmin-or-argmax